# Matlab freqz function in Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I am trying to implement a Python equivalent for the Matlab frequency response function

```
[h,f] = freqz(b, 1, 512, 12.5)
```

described in [here](http://se.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/frequency-response.html). My current attempt

```
f, h = scipy.signal.freqz(b, 1)
```

does not give the intended result. Trying the parameters `worN` and `whole` (see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.freqz.html)) do not seem to fix the issue.

How should it be done?

**Edit:**

Matlab example:

```
>> [h, f] = freqz(1:5, 1, 512, 12.5)

h =

  15.0000 + 0.0000i
  14.9976 - 0.2454i
  14.9902 - 0.4907i
  14.9780 - 0.7358i
  14.9609 - 0.9806i
  14.9389 - 1.2250i
  ...

f =

         0
    0.0122
    0.0244
    0.0366
    0.0488
    0.0610
    ...
```

Python example:

```
>>> f, h = scipy.signal.freqz(range(1,6), 1)
>>> h
array([ 15.00000000 +0.j        ,  14.99755288 -0.24541945j,
        14.99021268 -0.49073403j,  14.97798292 -0.73583892j,
        14.96086947 -0.98062944j,  14.93888050 -1.22500102j,
        ...])
>>> f
array([ 0.        ,  0.00613592,  0.01227185,  0.01840777,  0.02454369,
        0.03067962,  ...])
```

In other words, the Scipy function gives good values for `h`, but the values of `f` do not match.

Comment: Could you give an example of `a` and the expected output?

Comment: Also, your use of `freqz()` doesn't appear to match any of the uses shown in your link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 1.2.0 of SciPy, the `fs` argument was added to [`scipy.signal.freqz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.freqz.html).  So you can write

```
f, h = freqz(range(1, 6), 1, fs=12.5)
```

For example,

```
In [18]: f, h = freqz(range(1, 6), 1, fs=12.5)                                                

In [19]: len(f)                                                                               
Out[19]: 512

In [20]: f[:10]  # Matches the Matlab output shown in the question.                                                                       
Out[20]: 
array([0.        , 0.01220703, 0.02441406, 0.03662109, 0.04882812,
       0.06103516, 0.07324219, 0.08544922, 0.09765625, 0.10986328])
```

---

In older versions of SciPy,
`signal.signal.freqz` doesn't have an option to return the frequencies in Hz, so you'll have to scale the frequencies yourself afterwards.

The equivalent of Matlab's

```
[h, f] = freqz(b, a, n, fs)
```

using `freqz` from `scipy.signal` is:

```
w, h = freqz(b, a, worN=n)
f = fs * w / (2*np.pi)
```

For example,

```
In [15]: import numpy as np

In [16]: from scipy.signal import freqz

In [17]: w, h = freqz(range(1,6), 1, worN=512)

In [18]: h[:6]
Out[18]: 
array([ 15.00000000+0.j        ,  14.99755288-0.24541945j,
        14.99021268-0.49073403j,  14.97798292-0.73583892j,
        14.96086947-0.98062944j,  14.93888050-1.22500102j])

In [19]: w[:6]
Out[19]: 
array([ 0.        ,  0.00613592,  0.01227185,  0.01840777,  0.02454369,
        0.03067962])

In [20]: f = 12.5*w/(2*np.pi)

In [21]: f[:6]
Out[21]: 
array([ 0.        ,  0.01220703,  0.02441406,  0.03662109,  0.04882812,
        0.06103516])
```

Answer (score 1):

In both languages `freqz` expects numerator coefficients `b` for the first argument, not `a` like you wrote. Should be

`freqz(b, a, ...)`

Looks like you are trying to find the response of an FIR filter, for which there are only numerator coefficients and `a` is always 1.